# Navigation bar and Tab bar disappears when doing push segue

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue, uitabbar, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following structure in InterfaceBuilder in XCode:

- Tab bar controller

  - Navigation bar controller

    - View Controller A
    - .. push segue to..
    - View Controller B

However I cannot get the push segue to keep the nav bar and tab bar. It also animates from the bottom like a modal segue.

This is how I start the segue:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(DETAIL_MEETING_SEGUE_ID, sender: self)
```

Both VC1 and VC2 have unchecked "Hide Bottom Bar on Push".

In Interface Builder tab bar and nav bar are showing correctly. Also, when dragging a segue directly from a button to VC 2 with push set it works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same problem at the moment. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I wrote how I solved it below. Not the best solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it by dragging a manual segue from the tableview cell to "View Controller 2". I then gave it the same name as before and made setup in `prepareForSegue:` as normal. I had to drag multiple segues but it was ok to use the same id for them.

If anyone have a better solution please write it here.

Comment: can you explain a little more please?
what do you mean by giving them same name? I didn't get you !

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue after embedding tab bar stacks of VCs into navigation controllers. There was a storyboard push segue from VC a to VC b (in a different stack) that was called using performSegue:.

My fix:
Delete the segue in storyboard, then create it again the exact same way. After this the VC b showed the tab bar and the navigation bar as expected.

Filed a bug with Apple Bug Reporter.

Comment: Wow I cannot believe, but your answer fixed my issue. I think the problem was I added a push segue, then embedded the nav bar, and that messed things up with the segue. Deleting and create the segue again worked. Thanks!

Comment: OK, and what if the VC b in a Storyboard Reference what shall I do?
I did exactly what you said, but it didn't work!... maybe because I'm working out of the main Storyboard and my VC b presented  in VC a's Storyboard as Storyboard Reference!